# ajax page loading -Dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

Hi I have a page with a navigation menu on the left and when any link
on this menu is clicked , an Ajax get call is sent to the server and
the right side gets updated with the new page.

How I am currently doing this is by creating 2 columns, the left col
contains the navigation link and the right col contans a div named the
content which has a dojotype of dojox.layout.ContentPane.Now when the
data is received from the server, I  change its content like this

```
dijit.byId("thecontent").setContent=data
```

Now  when I click on the navigation link , the right side gets
displayed properly(this page has dijits and also some scripts to
handle onclick events). But firebug returns an error saying

```
"Tried to register widget with id==thecontent but that id is already registered"
```

my main dojo include looks like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"djConfig="parseOnLoad:false"></script>
```

I do a dojo.parser.parse() in the function dojo.addOnLoad like this:-

```
 dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
     dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
     dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");
     dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
     dojo.require("dojox.layout.ContentPane");
     dojo.require("dijit.Editor");
   dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        dojo.parser.parse();
        sendgetrequest();//this initiates the xhrget request
        dojo.removeClass(dojo.byId("doc3"),"hiddendiv");
        }

);
    })
```

I am also unable to run any scripts in this new loaded page. No onclick event is working, just the dijit widgets are displayed...

Comment: did you mean to have nested addOnLoad calls?  Might need to see the whole page to see what's going on.

Comment: Four things: (1) That top code should be `setContent(data)` not `setContent=data`, but I reckon you might have it correct in your actual code. (2) That error means you're trying to instantiate a widget with the same id twice - either you need unique IDs or you're not truly destroying a widget you intend to replace. (3) @peller, nested addOnLoads are valid the way they're done here, but really the outside addOnLoad is probably not needed at all.  (4) Echoing peller, it would help to see more code for context - i.e. what exactly is happening when a nav link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means, as Ken already said, that you are creating a dijit with an id that already exists. My guess would be that you load the AJAX content in the right panel without destroying the old right panel first.

Try calling destroyRecursive on the main dijit container in the right panel before loading the new content. Also, if you do not need to set the id of the dijit, you just might drop the id (but that would leave a memory hole because the old dijits are not destroyed).